# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am new cocos2dx v3.7 developer. Now i create the project in android and set all the enviroment variable.I create game in windows 64 bit using eclipse IDE.
I use Apache_ant 1.9.4 and NDK_root=android-ndk-r10d .
I also run the project using build_native.py file in command promt.When i run project in genymotion or in avd,project crash and logcat display eror

> 10-07 10:09:49.889: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 102592 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:49.897: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 86400 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:49.901: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 70208 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:49.905: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 54016 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:49.909: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 37824 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:49.917: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 21632 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:207)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:222)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   10-07 10:09:50.685: E/AndroidRuntime(2333):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-07 10:09:51.001: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 764896 bytes, got 16192 
>   10-07 10:09:51.005: E/SocketStream(120): readFully was waiting for 748704 bytes, got 16192

how can i solve this error;Thanks in advance.

Comment: genymotion is x86 - are you sure you compile for x86 and not just for ARM?

Comment: how can i identify that genymotion is x86 or ARM.

Comment: I try to run project in avd with intel_x86 then another issue showing in logcat that is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:   788 cannot locate 'srand'........i run on api level 10 , 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

> x86 and ARM is different, and they need different *.so* file, you can input the following command like this:
>
> > `ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips"`
>
> then refresh your project and run it in Genymotion, then you will succeed!
>   Good Luck!